# Express Server - GET request returns a 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, get

I'll cut to the chase... So I am trying to make a GET request to my server from my react (redux) app. As far as I can see, I've setup my express server correctly (a lot of my server is optimised for server side rendering)

**Here is my redux action**

```
import axios from "axios";

export function fetchTweets() {
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch({
            type: "FETCH_TWEETS"
        })
        axios.get("/api/articles")
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: "FETCH_TWEETS_FULFILLED",
                    payload: response.data
                })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: "FETCH_TWEETS_REJECTED",
                    payload: err
                })
            })
    }
}
```

**Here is my Express server**

```
import path from 'path';
import express from 'express';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import middleware from './src/middleware';

const app = express();

//------------------------

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    const config = require('./webpack.config.dev');
    const compiler = webpack(config);
    app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
        noInfo: true,
        publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
        stats: {
            assets: false,
            colors: true,
            version: false,
            hash: false,
            timings: false,
            chunks: false,
            chunkModules: false
        }
    }));
    app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));
    app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')));
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')));
}

app.get('*', middleware);

//---------------------------

//connect to mongo db
var db
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://###:###@ds123930.mlab.com:23930/halftimefront', (err, database) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    db = database
    console.log('db connected');
})


app.get('/api/articles', (req, res) => {
        console.log("test");
    var articles = [];
    //var articles2 = [];
    db.collection('articles').find().toArray().then(result => {
        articles = articles.concat(result);
    }).then(() => {
        console.log(articles);
        res.send(articles);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.error(e);
    });
});



app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.info('Listening at http://localhost:3000');
    }
});
```

**When I make the GET request from my redux action, it returns this in my client side console**

> GET http://localhost:3000/api/articles 404 (Not Found)

I've searched online and cannot find a solution to my problem, to me the GET request looks right, maybe I've not set my express server up correctly?

Any help or advice is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always place the `'*'` route after listing all other routes.

```
app.get('/api/articles', function() {});
app.get('*', middleware);
```

Comment: What i am saying is `*` matches with every route, so when you hit '/api/article' it matches with your `app.get('*', middleware);`, instead of your next route `app.get('/api/article', middleware);`. so you should order your routes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

```
app.get('*', middleware);
```

to

```
app.use(middleware);
```

When you create routing '*' at beginning it will catch all routes. If you want to add middleware to all requests you should use `app.use`.

If you want to add middleware to only one request

```
app.get('/route', middleware1, middleware2, (req, res) => {
    res.send('route with middlewares');
})
```